# How find this $\prod_{1\le j\le m-1,gcd(j,m)=1}\prod_{1\le k\le n-1,gcd(k,n)=1}\left(e^{\frac{2\pi j}{m}i}-e^{\frac{2\pi k}{n}i}\right)$

Tags: calculus

> Find this value
>   $$\prod_{\substack{1\le j\le m-1,\\\gcd(j,m)=1}}\prod_{\substack{1\le k\le n-1,\\\gcd(k,n)=1}}\left(e^{\frac{2\pi j}{m}i}-e^{\frac{2\pi k}{n}i}\right)$$
>   where $i^2=-1$

This problem I think is very interesting, and I can't find a solution. Thank you everyone.

My idea: I  Think we can must use Euler therom:$$e^{ix}=\cos{x}-i\sin{x}$$

then
$$e^{\dfrac{2\pi j}{m}i}-e^{\dfrac{2\pi k}{n}i}=\cos{\dfrac{2j\pi}{m}}-\cos{\dfrac{2k\pi}{n}}+i\left(\sin{\dfrac{2j\pi}{m}}-\sin{\dfrac{2k\pi}{n}}\right)$$

and use
$$\cos{x}-\cos{y}=-2\sin{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{x-y}{2}}$$
and
$$\sin{x}-\sin{y}=-2\sin{\dfrac{x-y}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}.$$

Comment: Why is this problem "very interesting"? What's the background, where does it come from?

Comment: I don't Known, How use English express,this problem background is find the two 分圆多项式的结构式

Comment: According to a translator, what you wrote is chinese for "cyclotomic polynomial formula". Thanks. Did you try some few explicit examples with some values of $\,n,m\,$ ?

Comment: Thank you,I have find http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%88%86%E5%9C%86%E5%A4%9A%E9%A1%B9%E5%BC%8F  and(http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%90%E5%BC%8F )?

Comment: I believe this is the same as calculating the resultant of the $m$th and $n$th cyclotomic polynomials - which has been addressed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257548/cyclotomic-polynomials-and-gcd .

Comment: and 结构式：meaning: this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Resultant.html