# A kind of GCD of cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

We know that in $\mathbb Q[x]$ that two cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n(x),\Phi_m(x)$ are relatively prime when $m\neq n$. This means that there are integer polynomials $a(x),b(x)$ and a positive integer $D$ such that:

$$a(x)\Phi_n(x)+b(x)\Phi_m(x)=D$$

The smallest such $D$ can be thought of as some kind of integer $GCD$ of the polynomials. I'm wondering if there is a good general formula for this?

Lets write $\langle m,n\rangle$ to be this $D$.

If $m=1$ then $$\langle 1,n\rangle=\Phi_n(1)=\begin{cases}p&n=p^k\\1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

If $m,n>1$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then we easily get that $\langle m,n\rangle = 1$, by the same argument that $\gcd(x^n-1,x^m-1)=x^{\gcd(m,n)}-1$, since the proof of that is entirely in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

When $m=p,n=2p$ with $p$ prime, you get $\langle m,n\rangle = 2$, since we get $\Phi_{p}(x)(1-x)+\Phi_{2p}(x)(1+x)=2$.

---

A related question is, given distinct integers $m,n$, what is the smallest $D$ such that for all integers $k$:

$$\gcd(\Phi_m(k),\Phi_n(k))\mid D$$

In general, this $D\mid\langle m,n\rangle$ but is not necessarily equal. For example, when $m=p,n=2p$ where $p$ is an odd prime, then $\Phi_m(k)$ is never even, so $D=1$ when $\langle m,n\rangle = 2$.

Comment: Perhaps you can try using the formula for the resultant given [here on mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclotomicPolynomial.html) or one of the references mentioned there. (formula 50) See also [A054372](https://oeis.org/A054372) (unfortunately without any further formulae)

Comment: Don't know enough about resultants to be able to tell what how it is related to this question, @flawr

Comment: Answer here I think: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257548/cyclotomic-polynomials-and-gcd/2314477

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The resultant basically is something like what you described: Given two polynomials $A,B$ it "provides" three more polynomials $R,S,D$ such that $RA+SB=D$ and $\deg R < \deg B$, $\deg S < \deg A$ and$D$ is zero iff $A$ and $B$ have a common divisor. I recommend reading through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition), in that sense it is some kind of generalized Bézout.

Comment: Ah, okay. It seems like in general, for two integer polynomials relatively prime in $\mathbb Q[x]$, my $D$ is a divisor of the resultant. But from the comments to that answer, it seems like the resultant might not always be my $D$.

Comment: Okay, the second answer to the above-linked question actually has the full proof. If $m=p^kn$ or $n=p^km$ for $k>0$, then $\langle m,n\rangle=p$. Otherwise $\langle m,n\rangle = 1$ (if $m\neq n.$) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2314477/7933